# What is the remote IP on PPTPD settings? ( digital ocean)

Tags: vpn, pptpd

I'm trying to install a vpn ( PPTPD) server using digital ocean [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp). Everything looks straightforward except that I don't know what the `remoteip` ip/range is. Is it something that I should look /scan from my server ? 
In the tutorial it says

```
localip 10.0.0.1
remoteip 10.0.0.100-200
Where localip is IP address of your server and remoteip are IPs 
that will be assigned to clients that connect to it.
```

I assume the localip is the Ip address that I'm using to connect to the server. However I don't know what the remoteip is because digital ocean [does not support](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-i-get-additional-ip-addresses-for-a-droplet) multiple Ip addresses. It is so frustrating !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a VPN. This VPN is tunneled in normal IP connections. The localip and the remoteip address are taken from [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) private address spaces as per the example.

In the example the Server will have aVPN  address of 10.0.0.1 and it will provide VPN addresses ranging from 10.0.0.100 to 10.0.0.200 to connecting clients.